# How Replacing empty string works

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

[Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18761#issuecomment-662509293) we have a solution that works for text overflow with ellipsis problem

> .replaceAll("", "\u{200B}")

I cannot understand why replacing empty string with ZERO WIDTH SPACE works, How is possible to replace empty string! how dart find empty string that is noting and replace it?

My question is: Why by running the following code, we get `XFXoXoX` result? We have same result in JavaScript too

```dart
final foo = 'Foo';
print(foo.replaceAll("", "X"));
```

Comment: foo.replaceAll(" ", "X") use like this

Comment: @logeshpalani98 Do you understand my question?

Comment: Not an expert, but I believe this has something to do with RegEx and how the replaceAll() method works. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html

Comment: The first argument is [Pattern](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Pattern-class.html), in this case is a `String` not `RegExp`

Comment: It's weird conceptually, but it just works the way you observe: it replaces the "empty string" before and after every character (actually every UTF-16 code unit) with the replacement.

Comment: @jamesdlin I don't think so, Is there any empty string before and after every character? I tested in JavaScript, `'Foo'.replaceAll("", "X")` is `XFXoXoX` too, WHY?

Comment: Is there an empty string before and after every code point?  Sure there is. `'x' == 'x' + ''` and `'x' == '' + 'x'`. =P Of course, there's an arbitrary number of such empty strings, which is the weird part.  Just accept that that's how the implementation works and move on.

Comment: Tracing the code of `replaceAll`, it uses the `allMatches` function, `''.allMatches(foo)`, which considers the empty string a valid match. I'm still finding out why though.

Comment: @jamesdlin What do you think about low level language like c? `char foo[] = "Foo"` is actually `char foo[4] = {'F', 'o', 'o', '\0'};` not `char foo[unlimited] = {'', 'F', '', 'o', '', 'o', '', '\0'};`

Comment: `''` is not valid in C.  In C, you could do `"" "F" "" "o" "" "o" ""`.

Comment: @rickimaru can you please show me the source?

Comment: @jamesdlin why? we cannot have a empty string in c?

Comment: An empty string in C is `""`. Single-quotes denote character constants.  A character constant denoting an empty string is nonsense.

Comment: OK, `""` is empty string in c, You told that `there's an arbitrary number of such empty strings. Just accept that ` , So why `char foo[] = "Foo"` is actually `char foo[4] = {'F', 'o', 'o', '\0'};`  and there is no `""` before and after?

Comment: I'm explaining that treating every character as being preceded and followed by an empty string is one way to interpret the requested action of replacing an empty string, which is what the implementation ends up doing.  Constructing strings with "embedded empty strings" is nonsense.

Comment: @WebMaster [Line 657](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/stable/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/string_patch.dart)

Comment: @jamesdlin I figured out what is your means, but `arbitrary number of such empty strings` can result `XFXoXoX` , `XXXXXXXFXoXoX`, `XFXXXoXoX` and unlimited number of arbitrary result so technically `foo.replaceAll("", "X")` is not equal to `foo.replaceAll("", "X")`

Comment: Exactly. All of those could be valid interpretations.  The specific interpretation that Dart uses is to treat it as if there's a single empty string before and after every code unit.